# Vue.js suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working with Vue.js, and for some reason it just stopped working. I can't seem to find my mistake - been looking at it for hours.

This is my HTML file - just dependencies and a table that displays the data in `users`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <link 
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" 
        >
        <script
            src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"
            type="text/javascript">
        </script>

        <script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <div class="container">
            <div id="app">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Personal Number</th>
                            <th>Volcano Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="user in users">
                            <td><% user.name %></td>
                            <td><% user.personal_number %></td>
                            <td><% user.volcano_amount %></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the app.js file - which just inits the Vue instance, creates the `users` array, and runs an AJAX request that updates the `users` array.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        users: []
    },
    mounted: function() {
        var vue_object = this;
        $.getJSON('users', function(data) {
            vue_object.users = data;
        });
    },
    delimiters: ['<%', '%>']
});
```

The result is extremely disappointing - Everything is in plain HTML. The table has 2 rows - the header, and a row with `<% user.xxx %>`, as if Vue did not exist.

I guess this means that something is not running, though the app.js itself does run (I tried adding console.log and it did print)

Hope you have good ideas :)

Comment: check your console log if you see errors, also remove `var app =` part and see what happens

Comment: console has no errors :( . Also, I'm not 100% sure I understood what you meant, but I tried removing the `var` part, and tried leaving it as `new Vue(...` and both did not work.

Comment: can you do `{{ users }}` after your #app div? see if the mounted hook is calling the jquery part correctly

Comment: Can you try moving your `app.js` include below `#app`?

Comment: Isn't `<% user.name %>` ASP syntax, while Vue's should be `{{ user.name }}` ? Or is it the same and I just learned something new ?

Comment: @sklingler93 's fix worked! Thank you very much, I would love an explanation for that!

Alex , Look at the end of my app.js , i've set custom delimeters since I'm also using Jinja - which uses the {{ }} syntax as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your app.js file in bottom of a body tag.
When you are doing:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
```

element with tag #app doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Just pointing out that the fix was proposed first by @sklingler93